# How to view number of running services of an application, in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How in Android Studio see the number of running services in the application?
In Eclipse I watched it pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor**

tap Devices and button -o-> -o-> -o->

tap Threads

Comment: there's no "Android" within the `Tools` menu item

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of running services in the application by applying some debugging lines in each onStartCommand of your Service Class. Hence, you can check for the number of running services.

Hope it Helps!! :)